# How to find out the block or xml responsible for code $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

I have a question about the below snippet. How to find out which file(.xml, .phtml) is responsible for the output. I have searched using Phpstorm in my Magento 2 directory thinking it's block name. It's just returning only one occurrence in entire project,  the file where I got this code (vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml )

```
$block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')
```

What is the logic behind it? How do I move forward if I encounter this again?

Answer (score 1):

The block with name customer.form.register.newsletter does not exist. These are just extension placeholders name which you can use in your module as a plugin point to inject your own blocks.

```
<?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()) : ?>
    <div class="field choice newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
        <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
    </div>
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

You can use it in your module as follows

customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <block class="your_custom_block_class" name="customer.form.register.newsletter" template="your_custom_block_template_path"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: yea it make sense